# Set font scale in Android emulator using adb

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb, avd-manager

I'm trying to change the font size in Android emulator (Pixel) programatically with adb. The commands are executed successfully but I see no difference in the font size. What is missing?

Already tried with other numbers (2.0, 0.5 etc) as well.

```
$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools/adb shell settings put global font_scale 1.5
$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools/adb reboot
```